# How do I write a TSQL function that takes a table name to drop, and drops a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Sorry, but I am new to TSQL so I don't even know basic things.   I've been working on this function, but I've been running into a lot of syntax issues.  If someone can assist me in writing this function, I would appreciate it.

1.  I would like it to check for the existence of a table before attempting to drop the table

2.  I would like it to check for errors after performing the drop action

3.  I would like it to print out status messages which include the name of the table

4.  I realize that I do not need to print out 'No Action Needed' but I am including it anyways to make the task slightly more challenging.

5.  I have run into a lot of syntax error issues that I do not know how to clean up

```
CREATE FUNCTION SAFE_DROP_TABLE(@TableName NVARCHAR(30))
AS
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) AND TYPE IN (N'U'))        
        DROP TABLE @TableName
        IF @@ERROR <> 0 
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Failed to drop ' + @TableName + ' Error = ' + @@ERROR
        END ELSE BEGIN
            PRINT 'dropped' + @TableName
        END
    ELSE 
        PRINT 'NO ACTION NEEDED'
    END
END
```

Goal: To learn TSQL as well as possible, as fast as possible.  I need to see and write as much SQL as possible.  I appreciate anyone who takes the time to respond.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't drop a table with a function: you have to do it in a stored proc. (Functions cannot modify the database.) Something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SAFE_DROP_TABLE(@TableName nvarchar(30))
AS
BEGIN

  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TableName) 
     AND TYPE IN (N'U'))            
        EXEC ('DROP TABLE ' + @TableName) -- note change here
        IF @@ERROR <> 0 
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Failed to drop ' + @TableName + ' Error = ' + @@ERROR
        END ELSE BEGIN
            PRINT 'dropped' + @TableName
        END
    ELSE 
        PRINT 'NO ACTION NEEDED'
    END

END
```

Comment: EXEC ('DROP TABLE ' QUOTENAME(@TableName)) -- Handles all table names & protects against SQL injection.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use EXEC to do this.

On the line that says DROP TABLE, you would do:

EXEC('DROP TABLE ' + @TableName)

BUT, I strongly recommend not doing this. Anyone could put any table name (or any other valid SQL in @TableName (called a SQL injection) and cause you all kinds of problems.

I'd read up on some database theory before getting too deeply into trying to learn T-SQL syntax.

SQL Injection Information:
http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953.aspx

Comment: Only if he calls the proc with user input--which is definitely not advisable.

Comment: let's say you have to drop 10 tables.  do I need to copy and paste the drop logic 10 times?  Is dropping 10 tables a scenario that just never happens in real situations?

Comment: It's pretty rare that you'd be dropping tables as part of your business logic. Tables tend to stick around for a long time.

Comment: But, as Ben showed you, it'd be easy to write a stored procedure and call it as many times as you need.